# SSRS - Include report in email body

Tags: email, reporting-services, report

How do I include the report in the email body? Can this be done in SSRS 2005?

Answer (score 1):

Use the format "Web archive" when setting up your subscription.  Yes it can be done in 2005.

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, Goto the Report, Goto Subscriptions...

You should be able to setup a regular email with the report in it.